# Attribute onmouseover not getting added in self-generated images

Tags: javascript, html

this is my js code

```
for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
    lineBreak = document.createElement('br');
    document.body.appendChild(lineBreak);

    for (j=0; j<7; j++) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = "immagini/c" + 0 + ".png";
        img.id = "i" + (j+1 + (i*7));
        img.onmouseover="freccia(" + j + ")";
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

actual html looks like that
[has no onmouseover attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tuY7.png)

how can I get my onmouseover into the element?

i tried, as for id and src, to manually assign it

Comment: Should be like: `img.onmouseover = freccia(j);` or rather avoid `mousemover/mouseout` for the preferred `mouseenter/mouseleave` - therefore use `img.onmouseenter = freccia(j)`. Also, you have not shown here nor explained what that `freccia()` function does, but do you know that you have the CSS `:hover` that could eventually achieve the desired?

Comment: Found out I had to use 'img.setAttribute("onmouseover", "freccia()")', thanks for the help anyway.